# Use instance variables or static variables in object instances that will only be instantiated a single time and won't be accessed from outside?

Tags: c#

Generally, are there any performance gain or any other reasons for using one way over the other?
Say I am having a winforms application and there will only be a single window per process ever. There are no comfort implications in my use case: The variable is only accessed from methods in that one form instance.

Comment: If you are writing code where any conceivable performance difference between these cases matters, you should probably not be writing in C#.  The difference, if any, will be tiny.

Comment: Is the application doing processing (it may be important) or is it for data entry (which the user will never see a performance benefit)?

Comment: In that case why not just make it private instance variable?

Answer (score 2):

You won’t notice a performance difference unless you are calling the methods millions of times. The question should be: Which variant makes more sense?

A static member makes sense in two cases:

1. All instances (and there should be more than one) share a common resource.
2. The class is static and therefore all members must be static as well.

Otherwise it seems natural to use instance members.

In the paradigm of [Object-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) (OOP) entities are represented as objects that have data fields (attributes that describe the object) and associated procedures known as methods *(freely adapted from Wikipedia)*.
Static members are not part of this paradigm and are not really object-oriented. It is the very reason of objects to have (instance) data fields.

---

Examples of common resources are: A database context, configuration options, a random number generator, the next free ID to be assigned to an instance.

Examples of static methods are factory methods. The `Color` structure, for instance, has `FromArgb`, `FromKnownColor` and `FromName` methods which all initialize a `Color` from different sets of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As far as performance is concerned, I agree with Eric J's comment. I would suggest making it an instance member, considering that designs change. Even if it doesn't ever change, there's really no advantage to making it static.